# Is there a way to turn strings into XML tags or search an xml document?

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to edit an xml document based on inputted values.

I need to be able to select what variables in the xml path I want to change.

```
    param(
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$xmlpath, 

        [Parameter()]
        [string]$variable,
 
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$xmltag
    )

[xml]$c = Get-Content ./filename

# I want to have the path go something like this but strings won't work
$c.$xmlpath.$variable.$xmltag
```

I've tried a few different things. casting as XML. Created the input parameter as just an object and tying in ABC.DEF.GHI (xml path).
I've also looked at Select-Xml but was unable to filter by $variable in my document

Has anyone experienced this issue? If so, can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could use a sample of the XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work, I used some XML from another question to test.

```
$XML =
[XML]@"
<monitor> 
   <fileProcessor>
    <pathConfiguration>
      <path>/path/to/file</path>
</pathConfiguration>
</fileProcessor>
</monitor>
"@

$monitor = 'monitor'
$FileProc= 'fileProcessor'
$path = 'path'
$config = 'pathConfiguration'

$xml.$monitor.$fileProc.$config.$path
```

You could also use XPath with `Select-Xml` instead something like:

```
(Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath "/$monitor/$fileProc/$config/$path").Node.Innertext
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Appreciate the help!